# Selenium Location field Auto dropdown is not selecting

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide, selenium-rc

driver.findElement(By.id("ProjectAddress")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("ProjectAddress")).sendKeys("Chennai");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='ProjectAddForm']/fieldset[4]/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ1UK.png)")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);`

Comment: Where is your code? the html? what are you trying to do? what happened when you tried to do it?

Comment: Its easy to identify the issue if u share the html or some more info about the issue

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("ProjectAddress")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("ProjectAddress")).sendKeys("Chennai");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ProjectAddForm']/fieldset[4]/div/div[1]")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);

Comment: Check the code  once ? And i tried by using x path and css selector

Comment: @sai please tell me the solution

Comment: is it a public website

Comment: can i try on that or else can u share html code of that element after displaying the results

Comment: http://getlancer.demo.agriya.com/users/login/?f=projects/add    Credentials :- employer /agriya.

Comment: After login Navigate to  Post project page dude..  In that Location field i'm not able to select an autocomplete dropdown option..

Comment: @sai if possible tell me you email id. i'll send full source code

Comment: saipawan.lingutla@gmail.com  I dont need code i need the way of displaying the suggestions in developer tool so that i can check how to identify the element.

Comment: Spend a minute putting all the question details inside the question so people don't have to dig through all the comments to find everything. Spend another minute properly formatting your code and HTML in the question so it can be more easily read.

Comment: @sai check your mail once

Comment: @JeffC My question updated properly, attached images and provided code also

Comment: Your code is not properly formatted and the images links aren't correct. Please edit them. See help for formatting advice.

Comment: @Prasad..Will check and let u know

Comment: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='Chennai']")).click();

Comment: @sai some how is the OP trying to click on a SVG element ?

Comment: what is the error u r getting

Comment: Syntax error on tokens , delete this token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Chennai, Tamilnadu")).click();
```